# index of second repeated character in a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying a hangman code in python. For matching a character of a word , iam using index function to get the location of character.
Ex :word = 'COMPUTER'

```
user_input = raw_input('Enter a character :') # say 'T; is given here

if user_input in word:
                print "\nThe Character %c is present in the word \n" %user_input 
                word_dict[word.index(user_input)] = user_input

#so the output will looks like

{0: '_', 1: '_', 2: '_', 3: '_', 4: '_', 5: 'T', 6: '_', 7: '_'}
```

Now , my problems comes when it comes with the repeated character.

```
# Another example 
>>> 'CARTOON'.index('O')
4
```

For the second 'O', how to get its index. since i have used this 'index' logic, i am looking to continue on this way.

Answer (score 9):

As per the [`str.index` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index), signature looks like this

```
str.index(sub[, start[, end]])
```

The second parameter is the starting index to search from. So you can pass the index which you got for the first item + 1, to get the next index.

```
i = 'CARTOON'.index('O')
print 'CARTOON'.index('O', i + 1)
```

**Output**

```
5
```

The above code can be written like this

```
data = 'CARTOON'
print data.index('O', data.index('O') + 1)
```

You can even have this as a utility function, like this

```
def get_second_index(input_string, sub_string):
    return input_string.index(sub_string, input_string.index(sub_string) + 1)

print get_second_index("CARTOON", "O")
```

**Note:** If the string is not found atleast twice, this will throw `ValueError`.

The more generalized way,

```
def get_index(input_string, sub_string, ordinal):
    current = -1
    for i in range(ordinal):
        current = input_string.index(sub_string, current + 1)
    else:
        raise ValueError("ordinal {} - is invalid".format(ordinal))
    return current

print get_index("AAABBBCCCC", "C", 4)
```

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution, based on the hangman game. 'CARTOON' was just an example. Hope u get what i am asking!!

Comment: @rajeshes Please check the generic version I have included now.

Comment: Your generic version always results in a ValueError, because the loop always completes and therefore executes the else block.  Can simply remove the else block.

Answer (score 2):

A perhaps more pythonic method would be to use a generator, thus avoiding the intermediate array 'found':

```
def find_indices_of(char, in_string):
    index = -1
    while True:
        index = in_string.find(char, index + 1)
        if index == -1:
            break
        yield index

for i in find_indices_of('x', 'axccxx'):
    print i

1
4
5
```

An alternative would be the enumerate built-in

```
def find_indices_of_via_enumerate(char, in_string):
    return (index for index, c in enumerate(in_string) if char == c)
```

This also uses a generator.

I then got curious as to perf differences. I'm a year into using python, so I'm only beginning to feel truly knowledgeable. Here's a quick test, with various types of data:

```
test_cases = [
    ('x', ''),
    ('x', 'axxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    ('x', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yz'),
    ('x', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
]

for test_case in test_cases:
    print "('{}', '{}')".format(*test_case)

    print "string.find:", timeit.repeat(
        "[i for i in find_indices_of('{}', '{}')]".format(*test_case),
        "from __main__ import find_indices_of",
    )
    print "enumerate  :", timeit.repeat(
        "[i for i in find_indices_of_via_enumerate('{}', '{}')]".format(*test_case),
        "from __main__ import find_indices_of_via_enumerate",
    )
    print
```

Which, on my machine results in these timings:

```
('x', '')
string.find: [0.6248660087585449, 0.6235580444335938, 0.6264920234680176]
enumerate  : [0.9158611297607422, 0.9153609275817871, 0.9118690490722656]

('x', 'axxxxxxxxxxxx')
string.find: [6.01502799987793, 6.077538013458252, 5.997750997543335]
enumerate  : [3.595151901245117, 3.5859270095825195, 3.597352981567383]

('x', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yz')
string.find: [0.6462750434875488, 0.6512351036071777, 0.6495819091796875]
enumerate  : [2.6581480503082275, 2.6216518878936768, 2.6187551021575928]

('x', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw_yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
string.find: [1.2539417743682861, 1.2511990070343018, 1.2702908515930176]
enumerate  : [7.837890863418579, 7.791800022125244, 7.9181809425354]
```

enumerate() method is more expressive, pythonic. Whether or not perf differences matter depends on the actual use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked how to find the second occurrence, and gotten an excellent answer for that, generalized for any specific occurrence. What you'll realize you actually want though is all occurrences at once. Here's a method for that:

```
def find_characters(word, character):
    found = []
    last_index = -1
    while True:
        try:
            last_index = word.index(character, last_index+1)
        except ValueError:
            break
        else:
            found.append(last_index)
    return found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the count method of the strings to find the number of occurrences of the user_input in the string. Then, use the str.index(sub,start) method for each occurrence of the user_input in the word and increment start by 1 each time so that you do not wind up getting the same index each time.

```
if user_input in word:
    count=word.count(user_input)
    a=word.index(user_input)
    word_dict[word.index(a)]=user_input
    for i in range(count-1):
        a=word.index(user_input,a+1)
        word_dict[word.index(a)]=user_input
```

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a one-liner if you use `filter` because if you use `index` you will be *forced* to either iterate or use recursion. In this case, there is absolutely no need for either. You can just filter out the values that are relevant to you.

Using `filter` is easy. An example implementation is the following one-liner:

```
def f1(w, c): 
    return zip(* filter(lambda (x,y): x == c, zip(w, range(len(w)))  ))[1]
f1('cartoon', 'o') # --> (4, 5)
```

You can always add error checking as in:

```
def f1(w, c) :
    if c not in w: return ()
    else:          return zip(* filter(lambda (x,y): x == c, zip(w, range(len(w)))  ))[1]
```

If the character isn't found in the string, you just get an empty tuple. Otherwise, you get all elements that match. If you want something generic, counting on the fact that there will only be one or two instances of a character is not the right way to go about it. For example:

```
In [18]: f1('supercalifragilisticexpialidocious', 'i')
Out[18]: (8, 13, 15, 18, 23, 26, 30)
```

Comment: Replacing range(len(w)) with enumerate: `def f1(w,c) : return zip(* filter(lambda (x,y): y == c, enumerate(w))  )[0]`

Comment: Yes, that is more Pythonic and certainly easier to read! That should have occured to me earlier. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Example.

```
a="samesame"
po=-1 # for this, po+1 is start from 0

for c in a:
    if c=='s':  # For example, I chose "S" what I want to find
        po = a.index(c,po+1) # if you find first element 'C' then search again in next postion
        print(po)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this answer is not properly formatted or I've messed up somewhere as I am new here and this is my first post. I have used the following code in my *own* Hangman games to get the index of multiple repeating letters in a word and has worked great. Hopefully a newcomer will understand this ok.

```
a = "hangman"            #the chosen word
length = len(a)          #determines length of chosen word
for i in range(length)   #this will loop through the code length number of times
    if a[i] == "n":      #n is the players guess. Checks if the letter is at index i
    po = a.index("n", i) # po gets the index of the letter if previous line is true
    print(po)            #prints the position/s
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def findcharpos(string, character, position=None):
    array = []
    index = -1
    while True:
        try:
            index = string.index(character, index+1)
        except ValueError:
            break
        else:
            array.append(index)
    if position == None and len(array) != 0:
        return array
    elif position > len(array):
        raise ValueError(f"The character {character} does not occur {position} 
                         times in the {string}")
    else:
        return array[position-1]
    return array
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
msg = 'samesame'
print(msg.index('s', 2)) # prints the index of second 's' in the string.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30296814)

Comment: @user17242583 this doesn't look like a comment. It looks like an attempt to answer the question. If you think it's not a good attempt you can downvote it, but we don't delete possible solutions...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ah I see - it looked like a comment before it was edited by Alex...